# Write internal link with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, href

I am trying to write some of my first jquery scripts but I'm having some problem... 
My page have a long text with lot of internal links (
 `<a href="/contents/Foo.htm" class=.internal>Foo</a>`
). I'd like that when you click on one of the .internal links, the href path will be opened inside the `<div id="article">`.

```
var InternalLink = function() {
    $(".internal").click(function(){
        var path =  $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "path",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#article').html(data);
            }
        });
    });    
};
```

I wrote the code shown below and it work perfectly but I am trying to generalize the code to every link with internal class:

```
$("#article_01").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'contents/article_01.htm',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#article').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: don't put a "." before the class name in the anchor. The dot is only used in the jquery to select based on class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="/contents/Foo.htm" class="internal" data-ref="article_01">Foo</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".internal").click(function(){
    var path =  this.href;
    var div = $(this).data('ref');
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#'+div).html(data);
        }
    });
    return false; // so the link does *not* follow through
});
```

So now all you have to do is change the `data-ref` to point to the div you want the html to load inside of.

Comment: this isn't going to work as there is a "." in front of the class name in the anchor. Need to remove from the html.

Comment: @scrappedcola thanx, sorry copied right from the OP -- wasnt paying attention to that lol

Comment: Thaks mate! but what have i to wrote inside the href? the data-ref is the url of the file that I wat to load inside the div but I can't understand the href. Can i just put "#"? I've tryed the script but it seems it is not working properly...I think the path var doesn't contain the correct path. In this example http://bit.ly/viKQrD the Chrome consolle tell me that "GET http://www.(MyDomain).com/example/path 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @Nicolaesse sorry i took the quotes off `path` don't know why they were there. (sidenote: shortened url's are frowned upon on stack exchange, try to use real url paths.)

Comment: @Neal now it is perfect! Thankyou very much!